# Having an error while removing duplicates in my c code

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, structure, singly-linked-list

So my code is almost complete and in the for loop where it is used to search for duplicates is where my code has a small logical error. could I get any tips on where i went wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct studentID{
    int value;          //a data member which is an integer
    struct studentID *next;         //a data member which is a pointer to next node
};


typedef struct studentID STUDENTID;     //creating a nickname for struct studentID as STUDENTID
typedef STUDENTID *STUDENTIDPtr;        //creating a nickname for STUDENTID as STUDENTIDPtr


//Global variables
STUDENTIDPtr previousPtr;           //pointer to previous node in list
STUDENTIDPtr currentPtr;            //pointer to current node in list


int main(){
    int checker[5];
    int removeDuplicate[5];


    STUDENTIDPtr newPtr1;           //creating a pointer to create a new node
    STUDENTIDPtr newPtr2;           //creating a pointer to create a new node
    STUDENTIDPtr newPtr3;           //creating a pointer to create a new node
    STUDENTIDPtr newPtr4;           //creating a pointer to create a new node
    STUDENTIDPtr newPtr5;           //creating a pointer to create a new node


    //creation of the first node
    newPtr1 = malloc(sizeof(STUDENTID));            //This is when a node1 is created
    newPtr2 = malloc(sizeof(STUDENTID));            //This is when a node2 is created
    newPtr3 = malloc(sizeof(STUDENTID));            //This is when a node3 is created
    newPtr4 = malloc(sizeof(STUDENTID));            //This is when a node4 is created
    newPtr5 = malloc(sizeof(STUDENTID));            //This is when a node5 is created


    newPtr1 -> value = 5; // assign data in node 01
    newPtr1 -> next = newPtr2;


    newPtr2 -> value = 2; // assign data in node 02 
    newPtr2 -> next = newPtr3;


    newPtr3 -> value = 4; // assign data in node 03 
    newPtr3 -> next = newPtr4;


    newPtr4 -> value = 4; // assign data in node 04
    newPtr4 -> next = newPtr5;


    newPtr5 -> value = 1; // assign data in node 05
    newPtr5 -> next = NULL;


    currentPtr = newPtr1;

    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");

    /*Loop to print the last 5 digits in my student ID*/
    printf("The last 05 digits of my Student ID are,\n");
    while (currentPtr != NULL){         //while not the end of the list
        printf("%d - ", currentPtr->value);
        currentPtr = currentPtr ->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");

    /*Assigning the 5 digits into an array*/
    checker[0] = newPtr1 -> value;
    checker[1] = newPtr2 -> value;
    checker[2] = newPtr3 -> value;
    checker[3] = newPtr4 -> value;
    checker[4] = newPtr5 -> value;


    /*This is a loop just to show that the values have successfully been addded to the array */
    printf("The List before removing duplicate digits is: ");
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        printf("%d", checker[i]);
    }


    /*This would be the loop to remove duplicates*/
    for(int i=0; i<=5; i++){
        int temp;
        temp = checker[i];

        for(int j=0; j<=5; j++){
            if(temp != checker[j]){
                removeDuplicate[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");

    /*This would be the loop to print the finalized list without duplicates*/
    printf("The List after removing duplicate digits is: ");
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        printf("%d", removeDuplicate[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Everything seems fine for now, But i'm sure that my for loop to search for duplicates is where i went wrong. My method was to take one digit and compare it with the rest. if it doesn't have any duplicates it puts it into an array and moves on to the next number.

As the final list, it must only contain 4 digits as `The List after removing duplicate digits is: 5241`

Comment: As a matter of style: `UPPERCASE` is generally reserved (used) for macros. So `STUDENTID` could better be something like `t_StudentId`

Comment: I don't think it is a _small_ logical error. The code does not make much sense.

Comment: You have a set of `newPtr` variables, you have an array `checker` and then an array `removeDuplicate`. I think that all should be one array, or just one linked list with a proper head.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie the catch is, I cant use functions nor loops to create linked lists. if that rule wasn't there I wouldn't even have this trouble at all. which is why had to do it all in the main function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters the arrays do not have any common with the list except that they store values of the data member `value` of nodes of the list. So you are not removing duplicates in the list.

The array `removeDuplicate` is not initialized

```
int removeDuplicate[5];
```

So this loop

```
    for(int j=0; j<=5; j++){
        if(temp != checker[j]){
            removeDuplicate[j] = temp;
        }
    }
```

has undefined behavior. And moreover this condition in the loop `j<=5` provides an access beyond the array.

The loops can look the following way

```
int n = 0;

for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
    int j = 0;

    while ( j < n && checker[i] != removeDuplicate[j] ) j++; 

    if ( j == n ) removeDuplicate[n++] = checker[i];
}
```

and then

```
printf("The List after removing duplicate digits is: ");
for( int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    printf("%d", removeDuplicate[i]);
}
```